# Default controller is not working when I use route php page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a project in this project 
when my URL

```
http://host/Bsheet_mvc/
```

Above is not working

```
$route['default_controller']        = 'Login';

http://host/Bsheet_mvc/index.php/login
```

When I use above it its working

This project is made in CI code igniter
.

Comment: Does http://host/Bsheet_mvc/index.php work ?

Comment: look at your htaccess and your controllers

Comment: If using codeigniter check have set base URL remove the index.php but you will need a suitable htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

This is case sensitive issue try this

```
    $route['default_controller'] = 'login';
```

'l' will be lower case